# Viewcontroller appear twice when I click cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, segue

I have a problem.
I have a ViewController embed in navigationController. 
And use the storyBoard to add the tableView in this viewController.
then,I add the segue.
Finally,I click the cell that the next viewController show twice.
I don't know how to fix it.
Thanks!

This is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  if(indexPath.row == 2){

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAdd" sender:self];

}

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAdd"]) {

    AddCommentViewController *AddCommentVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    AddCommentVC.CommentString = _DetailString;

}

}
```

Comment: I think both the segue and you call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. You should check this step `then,I add the segue.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the segue between both the `UIViewController`, not with the cell and `UIViewController`, as you have connected that segue on click of cell and you are calling the segue manually also that's why it is showing twice.

Do one thing, remove the segue and connect it between `UIViewControllers` then it will called only once.